# Expression-based table relation in QGIS, avoiding joins and relates

Tags: qgis, expression, table, concatenation, relation

In QGIS 3.18. I have two tables, one as a part of a `.shp` and the other a tab-delimited `.txt` with no geometry:

- my `.shp` attribute table contains a list of sites, and
- my `.txt` table contains a list of publications that mention some of those sites. For each publication (rows) one attribute (column) is `'Site'` and is a comma-delimited list of the sites mentioned in that publication.

I would like one to reference the other by a simple expression, if this is possible. That is: I want to **avoid joins and relates** (particularly, I want to avoid a N-M relation which was my original thought, but this will be unmanageable for my users and based on what I've read in the forums and such, it doesn't work very well in QGIS.)

What I want to do is something like this (my own syntax here):

- Expression for the field "Publications" in the Sites table (`.shp`) for Site A feature: 
  *Wherever the "Site" field of the Publications table contains 'Site A', 
  concatenate those publication names contained in the "Name" field of the Publications table.*

So the desired result, in the field `"Site A"` of the Sites table, would be something like `Publication 2,Publication 3,Publication 27,Publication 35`, where those publication names come from the `"Name"` field of the Publications table. See example in image below for clarity: 
[image: example]

What seems tricky about it is that it would be searching across multiple rows/features from the Publications table; something like a selection for all features containing 'Site A', then concatenating those publication names --  then doing that for all sites.

Is this possible? 
If this 'relation' can be dynamic (default value for the field for example) even better; if not, still good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution: basic principle

You can use QGIS expressions with `aggregate()` function ([see documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html#aggregate)): it's very use case is searching across multiple rows/features. **Additionally**, it is able to refer to any other layer, not just the current one where you apply the expression, thus making "joining" attributes possible.

To get a **dynamic** output, choose a virtual field: the content will then be updated if the entries change in the connected layer.

### Detailed explanation of how to fill in the arguments

1. Get the layer you want to get the information from (line 5), here `publications`
2. Define the kind of aggregation (line 6), here `concatenate`
3. Set the fieldname of the connected layer (line 7), here `publication`
4. Filter condition (line 8): only consider the entry if the field in the connected layer (here: fieldname `site`) matches the content in the current layer. This last step is a bit tricky, as inside the `aggregate` function, when referring to a fieldname, it only takes fieldnames of the layer defined on line 5.
5. For that reason, first create a variable (lines 1-3). The variable here is called `site` and contains the value of the field `site_name` of the current (sites table) fieldname. You can then refer to this variable using `@site` inside the `aggregate` function (line 8).

### The expression to use

```
with_variable(
    'site',
    site_name,
    aggregate( 
        'publications',
        'concatenate',
        publication, 
        filter:= regexp_match(site, @site), 
        concatenator:=','
    )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @Babel:  I'm pretty sure I want to be you when I grow up.  :)  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to hear that you appreciate the solution. QGIS expressions are great and are nicely explained in the expression string builder's help - so apart from asking here on GIS SE, that's mainly how I learned to use them.

Comment: Indeed! I am taking the plunge.

Comment: By the way @Babel, do you have any idea what is likely to cause commas to be added at the end of the output? It is happening to some, but not all, output values and I cannot for the life of me figure out why. In some cases, values that should be blank (there are no publications for those sites) end up looking like this: `,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: It seems that empty values are concatenated (I have the impression the `concatenator:=','` argument of the `aggregate` function is a bit buggy). However, I can't reproduce this behavior. Can you provide sample data?

Comment: Hi @Babel, I think I have figured out why I am seeing this behavior; it is indeed due to concatenating empty values. I don't suppose there is a way to tell it to ignore empty values? I haven't found one yet.

Comment: As a workaround, I'm trying to replace strings of commas with the `replace()` function, but as I am replacing double commas (`,,`) it is not an ideal solution. I am now working on replacing leading and trailing commas -- which I can do as a separate expression but not sure how to do it within the same expression.

Comment: To delete commas, use this expression: `replace ( [input_string],',','')` and replace `[input_string]` with the expression that genereates the empty values. For more info, please provide sample data.

Comment: I don't want to replace all commas, since the values are comma-concatenated in nearly all cases. Here is a sample extraction: https://github.com/pelodyte/tourb_qgis.  There are two .dbf files (one for sites, one for publications) and a file with the expression used (based on yours above). Note that all 'extra' commas are due to empty values in the `Intitu_abr` column, but I don't want to put values in there -- I want the expression to ignore the empty ones.